# Tried to change a if-else condition, but can it be better?

Tags: c#

I recently came across this code snippet, and I have tried to change it.

```
this.lblCheck.Visible = false;
this.lblBackup.Visible = false;
this.txtEmpNo.Visible = false;
this.CheckButton.Enabled = false;

if (matchedCode)
{
    if (checkBackdatedLeave)
    {
        this.lblBackup.Visible = true;
        this.txtEmpNo.Visible = true;
        this.CheckButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.lblCheck.Visible = true;

        if (startDate > todayDate)
        {
            this.lblBackup.Visible = true;
            this.txtEmpNo.Visible = true;
            this.CheckButton.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

into this:

```
this.lblCheck.Visible = false;
this.lblBackup.Visible = false;
this.txtEmpNo.Visible = false;
this.CheckButton.Enabled = false;

if (matchedCode)
{
    if (checkBackdatedLeave || startDate > todayDate)
    {
        if (!checkBackdatedLeave) { this.lblCheck.Visible = true; }

        this.lblBackup.Visible = true;
        this.txtEmpNo.Visible = true;
        this.CheckButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

However, I'm quite bothered with the line 
`if (!checkBackdatedLeave) { this.lblCheck.Visible = true; }`, as it contradicts with condition on the previous line. Is there still any improvement on this code?

Comment: [Please specify only the code's purpose, not a specific request, in the title.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/22222)

Comment: You can put the innermost if outside it's current block, but it won't really matter - this looks pretty clean. It won't be a contradiction in effect, only in readable logic - in the case the right part of the OR condition is true and not the left, the innermost if can execute.

Comment: your improvement is actually not functionally the same.  when `checkBackdatedLeave` is `false` and `todayDate < startDate` then `this.lblCheck.Visible` won't be set to true in your improvement but will be in your first code.

Comment: @IvoBeckers, nice catch! Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of [**Ivo Beckers**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/47901/ivo-beckers) already provides a viable solution. The only thing I would change is to place the three same checks in a variable and use that variable, instead of checking again and again. And only for `lblCheck`, do another check.

For example:

```
var status = matchedCode && (checkBackdatedLeave || startDate > todayDate);

this.lblBackup.Visible = status;
this.txtEmpNo.Visible = status;
this.CheckButton.Enabled = status;

this.lblCheck.Visible = matchedCode && !checkBackdatedLeave;
```